# Why is my microSD card not being reconized in Samsung Galaxy S Plus?

Tags: external-sd, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

I had purchased Samsung Galaxy S Plus, it was working fine, but I had a problem yesterday connecting it to my PC. After that my SDCard is not being recognized by my device. It says `Your phone doesn't have sdcard inserted` also when I try to open the inbuilt camera its also not working with a message as `Turn off USB storage before using camera`. I tried to check that my SDCard is not corrupted so testing in other devices and its working fine. I also tried to restart the device couple of times. So, can anyone suggest me what can be the problem here? why my SDCard and Internal Storage is not being detected?

Comment: you had problems connecting it to your device? Could you clarify please = which device?

Comment: @Sparx Its Samsung S Plus, already mentioned in the 
question.

Comment: >>I had a problem connecting it to my device.<< I inferred you had a problem connecting your Galaxy S Plus to another device.

Comment: Please read the question I had 
problem in connection to PC

Comment: You haven't once mentioned the word "PC" in your question. In any case, have you tried the suggestions listed below about safe mode or performing a factory reset?

Comment: Which ROM are you using Stock Gingerbread?

Answer (score 1):

If its connected to your computer and the USB connection mode is "Mass Storage", the SD card cannot be used by the phone.
You may like to change the connection mode by pulling the notification bar from top and selecting "Charge only" so that it does not mounts the SD card and it remains usable by the phone while it is connected to PC.

Comment: I am not able to see the internal storage also, its not the only issue with SDcard.

Comment: internal storage also gets mounted on the PC. You may see icons for two drives in "My Computer". Try changing USB connection mode to just charge the device.

Comment: yes but now I am not able to access any of them.

Comment: I can't see any option as `just charge`

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting another SD card and see if the problem continues. Else, copy all the data fro, the SD card onto your PC. Then, format the SD card and see if the phone recognizes it. If it does, copy back the data.

Also toggle the USB debugging mode - Android Settings > Applications > Development and see if it helps.

Comment: Tried everything it didn't work at all.

Comment: So, another sd card also not working indicates a hardware problem with your phone. Take it to your service centre.

Comment: Bu why I can't see my internal storage also?

Comment: try rebooting in safe mode and see if the issue persists. Last resort - factory reset. if that fails to solve the problem, take it to your service centre