# Why has my micro SD card suddenly stopped working in my Samsung Galaxy SIII?

Tags: external-sd

I bought a brand new Samsung Galaxy SIII on Tuesday and put my brand new 32GB SD card in it. It worked fine, populated my phone with all my music and movies etc.
I can even watch the movies on my TV wirelessly and view pictures... Amazing!

Anyway, I watched a movie through the new phone last night and reviewed my recent photos before bed. When I woke up this morning my phone said the SD card had been removed.

Now, the phone doesn't recognise the SD card anymore.

Can someone please advise me what has happened and how I can fix it?

Comment: You might want to check the Q&As in the "Linked" section to see if they solve your problem: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/how-to-fix-damaged-sd-card / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7289/micro-sd-card-physically-damaged / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22490/why-is-my-microsd-card-not-being-reconized-in-samsung-galaxy-s-plus / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25278/fix-a-damaged-microsd-card

Comment: I'm not sure if any of those mention re-mounting the card-- but that should work, too. 

The same thing happened to me a few weeks ago, but what wound up being the problem was that I had dropped it in my sleep, and the sdcard came ever so slightly loose. 
You might want to try taking it out and putting it back in again. 

Or, if its an old sdcard of a cheap-class, it could've finally died. 
In that case, I think Android has an "SDCard Read Error" notification.

Comment: Things to try: 1) Remove and insert card again. 2) Remove card and try it in another device. If it works in the other device format it in that device and insert again in the phone. 3) Try a different SD card in your phone. If 1 or 2 fix your problem - fine. If 3 does not work - your phone needs repair.